# Problem with linking static library in STM32CubeIDE

Tags: c, static-libraries, stm32, micropython, stm32cubeide

I'm having problems with including the MicroPython as a static library into an STM32CubeIDE project.

My ultimate goal is to run the MicroPython as a FreeRTOS task. At this point I don't have the FreeRTOS in the mix yet, I'm just trying to use the MicroPython library from my own app.

I have successfully compiled (with the provided make files) and ran the MicroPython minimal port (for STM32, https://github.com/micropython/micropython/tree/master/ports/minimal) and independently a little FreeRTOS test app with CubeIDE on my F407-DISCO board.

I then compiled the minimal port into a .a library file. I'm not 100% sure that the compilation worked perfectly, but at least I got no errors and a .a file that contains objects that seem to be the correct ones: [Some of the objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQcCy.png)

I have included the headers and the compilation succeeds, but the linking fails.

First I tried to include the .a file into the libraries like this: [CubeIDE settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4ucF.png)

But the build failed with error:

```
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a.a failed
attempt to open 
c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libm.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:68: FreeRTOS-test-2.elf] Error 1
"make -j12 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

09:12:18 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 4s.417ms)
```

I was told that the filename used in the -l option has to be without the lib prefix and the .a extension. So I changed the path like this:

[CubeIDE settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XnNh.png)

Then the CubeIDE did not find the file at all and the linking failed because of empty value is provided for the -l option:

```
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1\lib-mcpu=cortex-m4.a failed
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -l-mcpu=cortex-m4
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc\lib-mcpu=cortex-m4.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\lib-mcpu=cortex-m4.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib\lib-mcpu=cortex-m4.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1\-mcpu=cortex-m4.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc\-mcpu=cortex-m4.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\-mcpu=cortex-m4.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib\-mcpu=cortex-m4.a failed

....

attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libm.a succeeded
c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libm.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:68: FreeRTOS-test-2.elf] Error 1
"make -j12 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

09:14:24 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 4s.433ms)
```

Then I tried multiple different names for the library file and even placed two files in the folder, one with the name "libmicropython.a" or "libmicropython" and
another with "micropython" so that the CubeIDE finds a file it is looking for and also the linker can find a correctly named file.

To me this looks like the best attempt yet, but still it fails:

[CubeIDE settings 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cc6a.png)

```
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib\libC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../arm-none-eabi/lib\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a succeeded
c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-errno.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-exit.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-impure.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-init.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-malloc.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-memset.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-nano-freer.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-nano-mallocr.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-printf.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-sbrkr.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-strlen.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-findfp.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-fwalk.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-lock.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-mlock.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-nano-vfprintf.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-nano-vfprintf_i.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-reent.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-stdio.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-wbuf.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-writer.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-wsetup.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-closer.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-fflush.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-fvwrite.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-lseekr.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-makebuf.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-memchr.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-memcpy-stub.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-memmove.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-nano-reallocr.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-readr.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-fstatr.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-isattyr.o
(c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a)lib_a-nano-msizer.o
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libm.a failed
attempt to open c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libm.a succeeded
c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libm.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:68: FreeRTOS-test-2.elf] Error 1
"make -j12 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

09:16:32 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 4s.452ms)
```

I have also tried to set only the library search path (-L option) pointing to my lib folder, but then the build fails:

[CubeIDE settings 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsvWO.png)

```
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Core/Src/main.o: in function `main':
C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/Debug/../Core/Src/main.c:40: undefined reference to `gc_init'
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/Debug/../Core/Src/main.c:42: undefined reference to `mp_init'
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/Debug/../Core/Src/main.c:53: undefined reference to `pyexec_friendly_repl'
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/Debug/../Core/Src/main.c:60: undefined reference to `mp_deinit'
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.8.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: link errors found, deleting executable `FreeRTOS-test-2.elf'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:68: FreeRTOS-test-2.elf] Error 1
"make -j12 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

09:19:14 Build Failed. 7 errors, 0 warnings. (took 4s.582ms)
```

which to me looks like the linker did not find the library from the folder and therefore the references are still undefined. I don't see the -L option at all in the log though...

What am I doing wrong here? I'm not an expert of these things, so it might be something very simple. Perhaps with the compilation of the library file itself.

Any help is appreciated!

P.S. I had to cut down the logs so that they fitted into the post. If there's something critical info missing, I will add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

With the help of my colleague, I got it working. The -l option has only "micropython", not the absolute path, and the library search path points to "..", which is the root of the project.

The image below shows the working linker settings and .a file location.

[image: Working linker settings]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the library to the linker call instead of the general settings:

[image]

Comment: I've tried adding it that way too. Also, it seems that the two settings update each other, so that when I set the library in Paths and Symbols and then go to Linker settings it's there too.

Answer (score 0):

`c:/st/stm32cubeide_1.8.0/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\C:/Users/mhe/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.8.0/FreeRTOS-test-2/lib/libmicropython.a`

If you look at this path you will see that is invalid. It shoud be relative to your project location, not toolchain location.

Simply use button add and do not try to type it.

Comment: Yes, that path looks weird. But all I did was go to Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Libraries, click Add->Workspace... and then selected the file from the lib folder in my project. Please see my image "CubeIDE settings 3". 

I guess the CubeIDE makes up the complete path you pointed out. How do I fix it?